# Topological spaces for which $w(X)\leq |X|$ holds

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $w(X) = \inf\{|\mathcal{B}| : \mathcal{B} \text{ is a base for }X\}$ be the weight of topological space $X$.

For metric spaces and locally compact spaces we have inequality $w(X)\leq |X|$.

This inequality fails in general, even for compactly generated spaces as [Arens space](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000156/) shows.

I'm looking for a family of topological spaces which would encompass all metric and locally compact spaces, but for which the inequality $w(X)\leq |X|$ holds, but which would also be a family of spaces worth considering (trivially, we can just let this family to be all metric spaces and all locally compact spaces, but that's not a very good example...).

I realize this question can't be answered objectively, I hope that's not an issue.

Comment: Maybe it's a bit artificial, but you could consider "the class of all spaces where the network weight coincides with the weight".

Comment: Linearly ordered topological spaces and their subspaces satisfy this too.

Comment: Indeed, that's another example of a class of spaces for which the weight is equal to the network weight.